# creating input and output functions for postgresql custom type using postgis types

Tags: postgresql, postgis, plpgsql, custom-type

I have created a custom type in my postgresql database with this composite structure:

```
CREATE TYPE circle_geo AS (
       box geography(POLYGON,4326), 
       center geography(POINT,4326), 
       radius float8
);
```

so it is using some postgis types (POINT and POLYGON).
Now I would like to be able to create an INPUT and OUTPUT function for this custom type so that I can pass a simple string representation ( that would be (x,y),c like for the postgresql native geometry circle type) to create an instance of it

my input pseudo-function would look like this:

```
input_function(cstring) where cstring is of the form (x,y),r:

radius = r;
center = ST_MakePoint(x,y);
pdist = sqrt(2*radius*radius);
box = ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY[
                ST_Project(center, pdist, radians(45.0)),
                ST_Project(center, pdist, radians(135.0)),
                ST_Project(center, pdist, radians(-135.0)),
                ST_Project(center, pdist, radians(-45.0)),
                ST_Project(center, pdist, radians(45.0))
    ]))
```

and my output_function should simply return a cstring composed of

```
(center.x_lon,center.y_lat),radius
```

My problem is that I don't know how to writte these input and output functions. Can they be written in PLPgSQL or should they necessary be written in C? And if so, how can I made calls to postgis functions (like ST_MakePoint, ST_MakePolygon, ST_MakeLine, ST_Project...) inside them?
Any help would be greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2):

The type input and output functions have to be written in C, because they need to accept or return the type `cstring`, which is a plain C string that cannot be handled in SQL.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xtypes.html) which shows an example.

You can call PostGIS functions from your function either via the [Server Programming Interface](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi.html) (SPI), which allows you to execute an SQL statement, or faster by directly calling C functions exported from PostGIS (you have to link with PostGIS in that case).